# Got 90% of the JavaScript code - can't figure out the rest

Tags: javascript, function, math, matrix, linear-algebra

So I am trying to model [Gram-Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) for any size *N*×*N* matrix, and I have officially hit a roadblock I can't get past. I know it's a matter of looping this correctly, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Remember I do not want to just pass in a 3×3 matrix, but any size *N*×*N*.

The course notes *[QR Decomposition with Gram-Schmidt](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/Teaching/Math151B/handouts/GramSchmidt.pdf)* explains exactly what I want to do. Very simple calculation by the way. In the course notes ||u|| means that it is the sum of the square of the elements, so sqrt(*x*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + *x*<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + *x*<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + .... + *x*<sub>*n*</sub><sup>2</sup>).

The multiplication symbol is actually the dot product.

The code I wrote so far is listed below. What is wrong with it?

```
function qrProjection(arr) {
    var qProjected = [];
    var tempArray = [];
    var aTemp = arr;
    var uTemp = new Array(arr.length);
    var uSquareSqrt = new Array(arr.length);
    var eTemp = [];
    var sum = 0;
    var sumOfSquares = 0;
    var breakCondition = 0;
    var secondBreakCondition = 0;
    var iterationCounter = 0;

    //Build uTemp Array
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        uTemp[i] = new Array(arr[i].length);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        eTemp[i] = new Array(arr[i].length);
    }

    uTemp[0] = aTemp[0];

    for (j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++) {

        for (l = 0; l < arr[j].length; l++) {
            if (breakCondition == 1) break;
            sumOfSquares = Math.pow(uTemp[j][l], 2) + sumOfSquares;
        }

        if (breakCondition == 0) {
            uSquareSqrt[j] = Math.sqrt(sumOfSquares);
            sumOfSquares = 0;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < arr[j].length; i++) {
            if (breakCondition == 1) break;
            eTemp[j][i] = (1 / (uSquareSqrt[j])) * (uTemp[j][i]);
        }

        breakCondition = 1;

        if (iterationCounter == 0) {
            for (m = 0; m < arr[j].length; m++) {
                matrixDotProduct = aTemp[j + 1][m] * eTemp[j][m] + matrixDotProduct;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (m = 0; m < arr[j].length; m++) {
                for (s = 0; s <= iterationCounter; s++) {

                    matrixDotProduct = aTemp[j + 1][s] * eTemp[m][s] + matrixDotProduct;
                }
                for (t = 0; t < arr[j].length; t++) {
                    uTemp[j + 1][t] = aTemp[j + 1][t] - eTemp[j][t] * matrixDotProduct;

                }
            }
        }

        if (iterationCounter == 0) {
            for (m = 0; m < arr[j].length; m++) {
                uTemp[j + 1][m] = aTemp[j + 1][m] - eTemp[j][m] * matrixDotProduct;
            }
        }

        matrixDotProduct = 0;

        for (l = 0; l < arr[j].length; l++) {
            sumOfSquares = Math.pow(uTemp[j + 1][l], 2) + sumOfSquares;
        }

        uSquareSqrt[j + 1] = Math.sqrt(sumOfSquares);
        sumOfSquares = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < arr[j].length; i++) {
            eTemp[j + 1][i] = (1 / (uSquareSqrt[j + 1])) * (uTemp[j + 1][i]);
        }

        iterationCounter++;
    }
    qProjected = eTemp;
    return qProjected;
}
```

Comment: For starters, every `for()` statement you have must have a var declaration _somewhere_. E.g. `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {}`

Comment: @Lance it is not required to initialize a variable without var, the code will still work. That being said, all the variables will be global, not local, and so it is considered very bad practice to not use var.

Comment: Cool thanks guys I will add vars for all the i,j,m,l,etc variables I am using.  Good to know as well.  Appreciated.

Comment: To reduce code and increase readability, note that an expression `sum = x + sum;` can be written as `sum += x;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must apologize that instead of tweaking your code, I wrote my own from scratch:

```
/* Main function of interest */

// Each entry of a matrix object represents a column
function gramSchmidt(matrixA, n) {        
    var totalVectors = matrixA.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < totalVectors; i++) {
        var tempVector = matrixA[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            var dotProd = dot(matrixA[i], matrixA[j], n);
            var toSubtract = multiply(dotProd, matrixA[j], n);
            tempVector = subtract(tempVector, toSubtract, n);
        }
        var nrm = norm(tempVector, n);
        matrixA[i] = multiply(1 / nrm, tempVector, n);
    }
}

/*
 * Example usage:
 * var myMatrix = [[1,0,0],[2,3,0],[5,4,7]];
 * gramSchmidt(myMatrix, 3);
 *   ==> myMatrix now equals [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
 * 3 here equals the number of dimensions per vector
 */


/* Simple vector arithmetic */

function subtract(vectorX, vectorY, n) {
    var result = new Array(n);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result[i] = vectorX[i] - vectorY[i];
    return result;
}

function multiply(scalarC, vectorX, n) {
    var result = new Array(n);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result[i] = scalarC * vectorX[i];
    return result;
}

function dot(vectorX, vectorY, n) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += vectorX[i] * vectorY[i];
    return sum;
}

function norm(vectorX, n) {
    return Math.sqrt(dot(vectorX, vectorX, n));
}
```

Note that the algorithm above computes the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization, which is the matrix [e<sub>1</sub> | e<sub>2</sub> | ... | e<sub>n</sub>], *not* the QR factorization!

Comment: Wow thanks man, really appreciate it. Yea with the [e1,e2,...en] matrix I can put together the QR Decomposition.  The part that was tripping me up was the u(k+1) part.  

When I took Linear Algebra a few semesters ago I kept saying to myself, "Apart from Gaussian elimination, I won't use ANY of this other crap" and then I find myself opening up my old books and trying to figure out how to program it all in.

Again, thanks again.

Comment: I hope you can understand my code, and be able to reflect a bit about the structure and variables used in your own code.

Comment: I understand it, thanks.  I am most familiar with MatLab(my engineering uses) and as such I obviously do not have good programming fundamentals but your post greatly helped me understand how I should proceed.  It seems like the best way to approach it all is using short functions with easily understandable variables for debugging/tracking.

Thanks again

Comment: The main function that you wrote, "gramSchmidt" doesnt work, when the loop for (var j =0;....) is going, not sure what the goal of the loop is.  MatrixE[j] isn't defined for when j=1,2,3.... since that is what we are looking for.

I'm trying to fix your code and see if I can get it to work.  Let me know if you missed something and didn't post it :)

Comment: I tested my code and I'm pretty sure it's correct. The loop involving `j` performs the task of subtracting `(a[i] dot e[j])*e[j]`. `e[j]` is defined when `j < i`. I tried to structure the code to resemble your PDF as much as possible. Btw, please Accept the answer at the end when your original problem is solved.

Comment: Your right I had j < n and it wasn't working, switched it to j < i and it worked.  Sorry about that.  I don't like to just copy things so I followed your format and rewrote it more or less.

Comment: Sounds great! Do ask if you have any further concerns.

Comment: This is a great solution, but there are some bugs in the main function. The outer loop needs to iterate through the number of vectors, not the dimension size. Also the two extra matricies `matrixU` and `matrixE` aren't necessary (if you want to do the update in place).

Comment: @MattWay Thanks for the suggestion. I invite you to edit my code in order to fix the mistakes.

Comment: @NayukiMinase No worries, just wanted to make sure I wasn't stepping on your toes.

Comment: I have updated/fixed the algorithm (the reason it was working for you was that you were using the same number of vectors as dimensions), but I also changed it to be an in place editor (doesn't return a result copy), which might not be exactly what people want. I can always update it to return a copy if you like.